# Compare dates in Angular >11 with *ngIf

Tags: angular, date, components, angular-module

I would like to display some items only if their dates are newer than another date. So, on the `component.ts` i have:

```
constructor() { }
  currentDate = new Date();
  ngOnInit(): void {
  }
```

while I would like to cycle in `component.html` the relevant items from a list:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of itemList">
  <div *ngIf="(item.startDate | date:'yyyy-MM-dd' > currentDate | date:'yyyy-MM-dd')">
    {{item.text}}
  </div>
</div>
```

But unfortunately I am not able to display these data.

Could you please address me on the right direction? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

From how you have stated the problem, it looks like you are only interested in items whose date are greater than a specific date. I would approach it this way

### Approach 1

1. Generate a new property

```typescript
  constructor() { }
  itemList = [...];
  currentDate = new Date();
  newItemList = this.itemList.filter(({ startDate }) => new Date(startDate) > this.currentDate)
  ngOnInit(): void {
  
  }
```

2. Change html

```html
<div *ngFor="let item of newItemList">
  {{item.text}}
</div>
```

### Approach 2

1. Create a new property `isGreaterThanToday`

```typescript
  constructor() { }
  currentDate = new Date();
  itemList = [...].map(x => ({
    ...x, 
    isGreaterThanToday:  new Date(x.startDate) > this.currentDate
   }));
  
  ngOnInit(): void {
  
  }
```

2. In the html

```html
<div *ngFor="let item of itemList">
  <div *ngIf="item.isGreaterThanToday">
    {{item.text}}
  </div>
</div>
```

### Implementing a toggle of items

The simplest way to implement this would be to have another property say `showAll` that can be used to toggle, something like

```html
<label>Show All <input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="showAll"/></label>
<div *ngFor="let item of itemList">
  <div *ngIf="item.isGreaterThanToday || showAll">
    {{item.text}}
  </div>
</div>
```

[See this demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-fbpnnh?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

### Reactive Programming

With reactive programming we can modify approach 1 above. This would be the best approach to use for performance as it makes it easier to implement `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush`

In your TS file you would need to convert your variables to Observables and react to changes

```typescript
  constructor() {}
  showAllSubject$ = new BehaviorSubject(false);
  itemList = [
    { startDate: "2000-01-01", text: "Some past event 3" } ...
  ];
  itemList$ = of(this.itemList);
  itemListFiltered$ = combineLatest([
    this.itemList$,
    this.showAllSubject$
  ]).pipe(
    map(([itemList, showAll]) =>
      showAll
        ? itemList
        : itemList.filter(
            ({ startDate }) => new Date(startDate) > this.currentDate
          )
    )
  );
  currentDate = new Date();
  showAll = false;
  ngOnInit(): void {}
```

And in your html

```html
<label
  >Show All
  <input
    type="checkbox"
    [(ngModel)]="showAll"
    (ngModelChange)="showAllSubject$.next(showAll)"
/></label>

<div *ngFor="let item of itemListFiltered$ | async">
  {{item.text}}
</div>
```

[Below is a demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-bbsqh6?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: thank you, this is a clean approach. the point is that how could I implement this if `itemList` is a JSON file? Also, the html function approach - despite performance issues as stated below, seems to me more reusable if I am not wrong, for example if we have to deal with multiple JSON files. Correct me if I am wrong, I am here to learn :)
Edit: I've tried the Approach 1, it works! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Just a quick note: it seems to me that it should be 

`<div *ngIf="item.isGreaterThanToday">{{item.text}}</div>`

Right?

Comment: Yes, using functions is very helpful if you need to add reusability. Pieces of code can be moved to a function in any code. Just try to avoid having functions running in the html

Comment: Do you think it is possible to implement the Approach 2 in a user-driven behavior, as with a button, encapsulating the *ngIf inside an onClick method?

Comment: What behavior are you trying to achieve?

Comment: For example as the default view is the one for which the user has the future events, while it could be possible to revert that selection to show all items

Answer (score 0):

If the startDate is a Date object, I would do something like this. Create a function in the component

```
   function isDateStartingAfterToday(startDate) {
      return startDate.getFullYear() > this.currentDate.getFullYear() &&
        startDate.getDate() > this.currentDate.getDate() &&
        startDate.getMonth() > this.currentDate.getMonth();
    }
```

and execute this component in ngIf

```
*ngIf="isDateStartingAfterToday(item.startDate)"
```

Comment: Having functions in your html has risks of causing performance problem as functions are executed every time any change occurs e.g clicking an unrelated button would trigger the function

Comment: Yes that's true, but As per my understanding, even if we create an expression and pass it to the ngIf, it still gets executed whenever a change occurs right? This way at least we can keep the logic outside of HTML