# Compare date inside loop in component

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an array of objects

```
   this.List={[submissiondate:"14-Feb-2023",submissiondate:"15-Feb-2023",submissiondate:"17-Feb-2023"]}
   let currentDate = formatDate(new Date(), 'yyyy-MM-dd', 'en-US', '+0530');



<div  *ngFor="let Label of List">
   <span *ngIf="Label.submissiondate>currentDate">Passed</span>
</div>
```

I want to show the span only if submissiondate is greater than current Date

Any solution to solve this issue, Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Compare dates in Angular >11 with \*ngIf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66743100/compare-dates-in-angular-11-with-ngif)

Comment: @AnandSowmithiran:  I checked this link Approach 1 in this approach they have first filter but i don't want to filter i want all the records and in my for loop only based on condition want to display data and solution you can provide

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to filter out records in your for loop based on any condition, you can also add custom [pipe](https://angular.io/guide/pipes)

```
<div  *ngFor="let Label of List | isInFuture:'submissiondate'">
```

Rough pipe implementation could look smth like this:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'isInFuture'
})
export class IsInFuturePipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(arr: Array<any>, prop: string) {
       return arr.filter(x => x[prop] && new Date(x[prop])>new Date());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List = [{ submissiondate: "14-Feb-2023" }, { submissiondate: "15-Feb-2023" }, { submissiondate: "17-Feb-2023" }];
currentDate = new Date();
isPasses(Label) {
  return new Date(Label.submissiondate) > this.currentDate;
}
```

```html
<div *ngFor="let Label of List">
  <span *ngIf="isPasses(Label)">Passed</span>
</div>
```